# Eval a string to a callable JS function

Tags: javascript, eval

I need to eval  a function kept as string and then use it in JS code, here's the scenario:

Step 1

```
<textarea id="function_text">function test(e){ alert(e.id); }</textarea>
```

Step 2

```
var thatFunction = eval($("#function_text").val()); // returns undefined
```

Step 3

```
thatFunction.call({id: 100});
```

Is there a way to do that?

P.S. I'm aware of all security considerations, I just need 100 to be alerted at step 3!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to give you a warning, don't do it, but here is how:

```
var thatFunction = Function('return ' + $("#function_text").val())();
thatFunction.call({id: 100});
```

Comment: Good enough for me, like that it keeps the eval'ed stuff to a minimum, the function name is not part of it.

Comment: Can I enject some context into eval call using your approach? I want some functions existing in a parental context to be recognizable?

Comment: Using call, apply or bind? Yes, since you are returning a function you can add any context you want. Or do you mean injecting existing functions from you current scope. That should also work.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the string will be evaluated as *function declaration* and not produce a return value, and that's why `eval` returns `undefined`.

You could concatenate the function declaration with your variable assignment:

```
eval('var thatFunction = ' + $("#function_text").val());
```

**or** simply call the function by the name it has (it you know it):

```
test.call({id: 100});
```

---

You might not want to use the variable name in the string. That's not a problem, all you have to do is force `eval` to consider the function definition as *function expression* and have it return the function. For example, you can do this by using the *grouping operator*:

```
var thatFunction = eval('(' + $("#function_text").val() + ')');
```

A more obscure way would be the *comma operator*:

```
var thatFunction = eval('0,' + $("#function_text").val());
```

Comment: I don't need it to return, I need a piece of of function for future calls.

Comment: `eval` returns the result if the last statement is an expression. But since you have no expression, the return value of `eval` is `undefined`. That's what I meant.