# eval within a function

Tags: javascript, eval

So guys, this one is probably a simply answered question. While working through eloquent javascript I came across an example where he uses the new Function constructor. I wanted to try reverse engineering this constructor with my own function createWithEval using, you guessed it, the eval() function. My function takes a name, arg, and body parameter which are all strings.

```
 function createWithEval(name,arg,body){ 
      var bdy= "function ";
      var body2=name;
      var body3="("
      var body4=arg;
      var body5=")"
      bdy+=body2+=body3+=body4+=body5;
      var body6="{";
      var body7=body;
      var body8="}";
      bdy+=body6+=body7+=body8;
      console.log(bdy)
     return bdy;
    }
    eval(createWithEval("xtimesy","x,y","return x*y"));
    console.log(xtimesy(2,3))
```

The code above creates the xtimesy function as intended, but when I try to place the eval statement within the function, the function pops undefined when declared

```
function createWithEval(name,arg,body){ 
  var bdy= "function ";
  var body2=name;
  var body3="("
  var body4=arg;
  var body5=")"
  bdy+=body2+=body3+=body4+=body5;
  var body6="{";
  var body7=body;
  var body8="}";
  bdy+=body6+=body7+=body8;
  console.log(bdy)
return eval(bdy); //should declare and return the xtimesy function
}
createWithEval("xtimesy","x,y","return x*y"); 
console.log(xtimesy(2,3)) // ---> xtimesy is undefined
```

I think I may have a scope error or an improper understanding of how the eval function works. Any input and/or solutions are welcome.

Comment: If `createWithEval` would *return* the function, you'd need to write `var xtimesy = createWithEval("xtimesy","x,y","return x*y");` to make it callable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eval a string to a callable JS function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17792406/1048572)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you are running `eval` within the `createWithEval` function, and it is therefore not available outside the scope of `createWithEval`. One way to correct this would be to use `eval.apply(window,[bdy])` to run `eval` on the global scope:

```
function createWithEval(name,arg,body, ctx){ 
  var bdy= "function ";
  var body2=name;
  var body3="("
  var body4=arg;
  var body5=")"
  bdy+=body2+=body3+=body4+=body5;
  var body6="{";
  var body7=body;
  var body8="}";
  bdy+=body6+=body7+=body8;
    eval.apply(window, [bdy]);
}
createWithEval("xtimesy","x,y","return x*y");
console.log(xtimesy(2,3))
```

Comment: `eval.apply` does not change a thing.

Comment: Uh, sorry, I should have been clear: *Using `apply`* in itself does change a thing, but thinking that the receiver context matters [is very wrong](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/#windoweval). Don't pass `this` or `window` or anything - it doesn't matter. Just use `eval.call(null, bdy)` or `(1,eval)(bdy)`.